# Get data from previous page

Tags: get

I create a popup window using `onclick="window.open()"` the question is how can i get the data from previous page? here is my code :

```
<?php
include ("conn.php");
extract($_GET); 

$applicantID = $_GET['applicantID'];          
$sql = "SELECT * FROM applicant WHERE applicantID ='$applicantID'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo $data['applicantID'];
```

?>

When i echo `$data['applicantID'];` it doesn't show any data.

I use this `<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="window.open('checkstatus.php','popup','width=800,height=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0'); return false" />`

Comment: show me the url you are giving in window .open function

Comment: where have you connect to databse

Comment: i use include ("conn.php") and the database connection inside conn.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `window.open('checkstatus.php?applicantID=something')`? And retrieve it by `$applicantID = $_GET['applicantID']` so that I hope it will work.